# Error while adding WebSphere in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, websphere, classpath

I am trying to use WebSphere v6.0 with Eclipse. When I try to add the runtime server for a Dynamic Web Project, I get the following error:

> Missing classpath entry \your_server_root\was-6.0\properties

Why?

Comment: This is a hopelessly outdated setup (6.0). What exactly does not work, your question is unclear? Could you create a server in eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My thought?  Add that entry to the CLASSPATH.

Another thought would be to ditch WebSphere and use Tomcat, JBOSS, or Glassfish.